# Group an image with text in an un-word-wrappable group in HTML5

Tags: html

In HTML, is it possible to have a group of an image and text that cannot be broken by word wrapping? i.e. would either be rendered together on one line, or wrap together to the next?

This can be done with words, by using `&nbsp;` but I want to add a small, letter sized icon to this group.

Example:

```
<p>
  Some some normal, wrappable text 
  <span class="unbreakable"><a><img src="logo.png"></a>&nsbp;<a>Product&nbsp;Name</a></span>
</p>
```

NB. for brevity I have removed the attributes from the `<a>` tags.

Currently, it is possible for the "logo.png" image to appear on one line, and "Product Name" on the next.

This code is part of a resizable element, sometimes it will be capable of being rendered on 1 line, others it will need to, so I don't want to force a `<br>` for the times it is not needed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TWvFY/ like this?

Comment: Oops, may be I misunderstood your question. Do you mean that you want to make the logo and the "Product Name" un-"wrappable" as a whole part, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Z3VV/1/ ?

Comment: Perfect! Want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending from comment:

As you want to combine logo and product name as a whole "un-wrappable" part, you can use `white-space:nowrap`:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z3VV/1/)

```
.unbreakable
{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```